# Filling Null Values based on conditions on other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I want to fill the Null values in the first column based on the value of the 2nd column. 
(For example)

1. For "Apples" in col2, the value should be 12 in places of Nan in the col1
2. For "Vegies", in col2 the value should be 134 in place of Nan in col1

For every description, there is a specific code(number) in the 1st column. I need to map it somehow.

(IGNORE the . (dots)

All I can think of is to make a dictionary of codes and replace null but's that very hardcoded.

Can anyone help?

```
col1. col2

12.     Apple

134.    Vegies

23.     Oranges

Nan.    Apples

Nan.    Vegies

324.    Sugar

Nan.    Apples
```

Comment: Add your data as text, not as picture, since we cannot copy and paste a picture to test ourselves.

Comment: Hey, yes I have changed it. Can you have a loot at it now. Thanks

Comment: Oke, but in your actual data. `Apple` is part of a sentence right? So it's `Apple fell from a tree`. We saw that in your picture.

Comment: @Erfan Yes, it's part of the description of the code. There are many descriptions and for each description there are specific codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reupdate

Here, I replicate your DF, and the implementation:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
l1 = [12, 134, 23, np.nan, np.nan, 324, np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]
l2 = ["Apple","Vegies","Oranges","Apples","Vegies","Sugar","Apples","Melon","Melon","Grapes"]
df = pd.DataFrame(l1, columns=["col1"])
df["col2"] = pd.DataFrame(l2)

df
Out[26]: 
    col1     col2
0   12.0    Apple
1  134.0   Vegies
2   23.0  Oranges
3    NaN   Apples
4    NaN   Vegies
5  324.0    Sugar
6    NaN   Apples
7    NaN    Melon
8    NaN    Melon
9    NaN   Grapes
```

Then to Replace the Null values based on your rules:

```
df.loc[df.col2 == "Vegies", 'col1'] = 134
df.loc[df.col2 == "Apple", 'col1'] = 12
```

If you want to apply these to a larger scales, consider make a dictionary first:
for example is:

```
item_dict = {"Apples":12, "Melon":65, "Vegies":134, "Grapes":78}
```

Then apply all of these to your dataframe with this custom function:

```
 def item_mapping(df, dictionary, colsource, coltarget):
    dict_keys = list(dictionary.keys())
    dict_values = list(dictionary.values())
    for x in range(len(dict_keys)):
        df.loc[df[colsource]==dict_keys[x], coltarget] = dict_values[x]
    return(df)
```

Usage Examples:

```
item_mapping(df, item_dict, "col2", "col1")
    col1     col2
0   12.0    Apple
1  134.0   Vegies
2   23.0  Oranges
3   12.0   Apples
4  134.0   Vegies
5  324.0    Sugar
6   12.0   Apples
7   65.0    Melon
8   65.0    Melon
9   78.0   Grapes
```

Comment: Hey, yes I can set for two values. But there are so many values and for every descriptions, many codes. Isn't there a faster way?

Comment: yes, you can just apply the loop method with for, applying these concepts, make any values and descriptions a list to be loop

Comment: Hi @Jovan, thanks for this solution. Do you know how I would go about tweaking it if I have 2 sets of conditions AND require the dictionary?

My df has nulls in both country and region columns. The lang column does not have nulls. I want to add the country based on the lang, and then add the region based on the country. I have created two dictionaries `country_item = {"id":'ID', "en":'USA'...}` and  `region_item = {"ID":'APAC', "USA":'AM'...}`. Then I used your "item_mapping" function which works but I cant use it on the entire dataset because of risk of overwriting existing non-null values.